# Return 404 with TomEE and Intellij

Tags: java, tomcat, http-status-code-404, apache-tomee

I created a sample Jakarta EE web application which is auto-generated by IntelliJ.

I deployed the war file to TomEE (9.0) and It returns 404 error.

I deployed the same war file to Tomcat (10.0) and it shows me index.jsp successfuly.

I wonder why TomEE is not working?

I downloaded it (webprofile) from https://tomee.apache.org/download.html
(latest one, TomEE 9.0)

TomEE
[TomEE 404 status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5FsG.png)

Tomcat
[Tomcat Successful index.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjSve.png)

[Create Sample Project - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFJAy.png)

[Create Sample Project - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41UNE.png)

I tried everything I can do.

Application context and url path are same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I found the answer: You should exactly match application context with your war file name

I don't believe IntelliJ will do this for you

Example:

WAR: `DEMO-1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`

Application Context: `DEMO-1-1.0-SNAPSHOT`

It looks like Tomcat does not care about this?

TomEE is strict.